# joomla module params show image in backend

Tags: joomla, module, field

how to show image in module field params and in backend? like the following code

```
<field
                    name="imagesspec"
                    type="ooooooooooo"
                    image="spec.png"
                />
```

the img not work in module params

```
<fieldset name="basic">
<img src="xxxxx.jpg">
```

I google it many days but there no any example or answer

```
            <fields name="params">
                <fieldset name="basic">
            <!-- Is it possible? -->
            <field name="imagesspec" type="ooooooooooo" image="spec.png"/>


<img src="xxxxxxxx">   <--it's not work
    ..
    ..
    bla bla bla 
                </fieldset>
            </fields>
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution,add a customfield type,nothing more